# Error message: [2011-11-18 10:40:31 - Notepadv1] AndroidManifest.xml file missing?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am trying to do the notepad tutorials and keep getting this error.

I am following all the directions on the website.

I have tried the "Fix Project Properties" via "Android Tools" but this does nothing to fix the problem.

I have put the extracted folder for the tutorial in various locations - this did nothing.

I am trying to create a new Android project from source with 2.1...

I have been told to uninstall Eclipse.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried, restart eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem, and for me it was caused by already having the extracted source code (which I was trying to import into the new project) in the same directory as where I wanted to created the project. So, don't put the extracted files in your eclipse workspace.

Answer (score 0):

This could be (and mainly is for me) caused by some form error in the XML. I would scour your XML and check to verify that you have missed something somewhere.

Comment: This is the code from the android tutorials. I haven't done anything with it yet. And my classmates have all installed the tutorials successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create New Android Sample Project, select Android 2.1 target and choose NotePad example .